# Angular 10 - Error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when trying to display a Google map based on coordinates retrieved from MapBox

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, mapbox

I am trying to display a Google map of a neighborhood based on coordinates I am fetching from the MapBox API.

I have a MapDialog function that is called when the "Show on Map" button is clicked along with a search component that display the list of daycares and a map component that handles the displaying of the map to the user. I have also created a service where the API call is being made. The error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined." is displayed when clicking on the button which should bring up the map. I think I have narrowed down the problem and I believe it is because the map component requires the coordinates from the API to be available before clicking the button but in this case the coordinates are only available after.

I tried to use a setTimeout function like so and the error no longer appears but the map appears blank when clicking the button.

```
const config: ModalOptions = {
      initialState: {
        list: [{ nurserySearch: nurserySearch }],
        title: this.mapTitle,
        point: setTimeout(() => {
          this.center[0]
        }, 1000),
        // id: this.nurseryIds[id]
      },
      class: 'modal-lg map-container',
      animated: true,
};
```

Relevant snippets from **nursery-search.component.ts**

```
searchResults: NurserySearchResultDto[] = [];
addresses: string[] = [];
center: number[][];
mapTitle: string;

MapDailog(nurserySearch) {
    this._nurseryService.searchGet(nurserySearch).subscribe((res) => {
      // console.log(res);
      this.nurseryDetails = res;
      this.getCoords(this.nurseryDetails.neighborhoodName + "," + this.nurseryDetails.provinceName);
      this.mapTitle = this.nurseryDetails.name + ", " + this.nurseryDetails.neighborhoodName;
    })
    console.log(this.center);
    const config: ModalOptions = {
      initialState: {
        list: [{ nurserySearch: nurserySearch }],
        title: this.mapTitle,
        point: this.center[0],
        // id: this.nurseryIds[id]
      },
      class: 'modal-lg map-container',
      animated: true,
    };
    console.log(nurserySearch);
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(MapModalComponent, config);
    this.bsModalRef.content.closeBtnName = 'Close';
}

getCoords(placeName) {
    this._HomeAppService.getPlace(placeName)
      .subscribe((features: Feature[]) => {
        this.addresses = features.map(feat => feat.place_name);
        this.center = features.map(feat => feat.center);
        console.log(this.addresses);
        console.log(this.center);
      })
}
```

Relevant snippits from the template **nursery-search.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of searchResults ;let i = index">

 <div class="daycare-info row">
  <a [ngClass]="{'dimed':!item.nurseryGalleryVideos?.length && ! item.nurseryGalleryTours?.length}" (click)="videoDailog(item.nurseryGalleryVideos , item.nurseryGalleryTours, 'video')" class="watch hover-effect"><i class="ti ti-control-play"></i>
                                {{l('Watch Video / Virtual Tour')}}
                            </a>
  <a [ngClass]="{'dimed':item.geoLocation}" (click)="MapDailog(item.id)" class="maplocation hover-effect"><i class="ti ti-map-alt"></i>{{l('Show On Map')}}</a>
  <!-- TODO: a-routerlink -->
  <a [routerLink]="['nursery-details',item.id]" class="book hover-effect">
    <i class="ti ti-more"></i>{{l('More Information')}}</a>
 </div>

</div>
```

**map-modal.component.ts**

```
import { AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Injector, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/app-component-base';
import { API_BASE_URL, NurserySearchDetailsDto, NurseryServiceProxy } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
import { Feature, HomeAppService } from 'home/home-app.service';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

declare var google: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-modal',
  templateUrl: './map-modal.component.html',
  providers: [MessageService],
  styleUrls: ['./map-modal.component.css']
})
export class MapModalComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {
  list: any[] = [];
  title: string;
  closeBtnName: string;
  options: any;

  overlays: any[];

  dialogVisible: boolean;

  markerTitle: string;

  selectedPosition: any;

  infoWindow: any;

  draggable: boolean;

  nurseryDetails: NurserySearchDetailsDto;
  provinceName: string;
  imageBaseUrl: string;

  point: any;
  id: any;

  addresses: string[] = [];
  center: number[][];
  mapTitle: string;
  newPoint: number[][];

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService,
    private _HomeAppService: HomeAppService,
    private _nurseryService: NurseryServiceProxy,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    public bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private injector: Injector,) {
    super(injector);
    this.imageBaseUrl = this.injector.get(API_BASE_URL);
  }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.point);
    console.log(this.list);
    this.options = {
      center: { lat: this.point[1], lng: this.point[0] },
      zoom: 14
    };
    this.initOverlays();
    this.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  }

  public onCancel(): void {
    //this.onClose.next(false);
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
  }

  initOverlays() {
    this.overlays = [
      new google.maps.Marker({ position: { lat: this.point[1], lng: this.point[0] }, title: this.title }),
    ];

  }
  handleOverlayClick(event) {
    let isMarker = event.overlay.getTitle != undefined;
    if (isMarker) {
      let title = event.overlay.getTitle();
      this.infoWindow.setContent('<div>' + title + '</div>');
      this.infoWindow.open(event.map, event.overlay);
      event.map.setCenter(event.overlay.getPosition());
    }
  }
  zoomIn(map) {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
  }

  zoomOut(map) {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
  }

  getCoords(placeName) {
    this._HomeAppService.getPlace(placeName)
      .subscribe((features: Feature[]) => {
        this.addresses = features.map(feat => feat.place_name);
        this.center = features.map(feat => feat.center);
        console.log(this.addresses);
        console.log(this.center);
      })
  }
}
```

**map-modal.component.html**

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header alert-primary texturperant">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="AdminDialog">{{title}}</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()"> <span
                aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body pl-0 pr-0 map-body">
        <ng-container>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <p-gmap [options]="options" (onOverlayClick)="handleOverlayClick($event)"  [overlays]="overlays" [style]="{'width':'100%','height':'320px'}" ></p-gmap>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
            (click)="onCancel()">{{closeBtnName ? closeBtnName : l('Close') }}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

If any more information is required, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what you are getting in the consoles for `console.log(this.center)` but, i doubt that, there is nothing coming there. Just to be sure, try adding a check in your function like this:

```
const config: ModalOptions = {
      initialState: {
        list: [{ nurserySearch: nurserySearch }],
        title: this.mapTitle,
        point: setTimeout(() => {
          if (this.center & (this.center.length > 0)) {
            this.center[0];
          } else null;
        }, 1000),
        // id: this.nurseryIds[id]
      },
      class: 'modal-lg map-container',
      animated: true,
};
```

null is just to avoid any console errors, the if condition will basically check if it has it then only it assigns, otherwise, it wont.

Please let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but got the following error: The left hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type "any", "number", "bigint", or enum type. However, shortly after I was able to fix it. Instead of `point: setTimeout()` I enclosed the entire ModalOptions along with `this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(MapModalComponent, config);` and `this.bsModalRef.content.closeBtnName = 'Close';`  in a setTimeout function. I believe this works because it ensures that the map coordinates are available prior to the map component being initialized.